# Translating a view from one coordinate to another in android

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I am working on an application where i need to translate a view from one cordinate to another. 
x1 = 191, y1 = 300
x2 = 50 , y2 = 150

I used the following code, but its behaving very strangly, I mean it's nor translating between those  two points.

Code:

```
        Animation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, x,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, pawnInitLocation[0],
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, y,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, pawnInitLocation[1]);
        transAnim.setDuration(1000);
        transAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
        transAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        v.startAnimation(transAnim);
```

I am new to animations in android and havent really achieved anything like this. Any help would be great.

Comment: are you performing these actions on the UI thread?

Comment: yup, am performing these on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x & y are evet.getRawX() and event.getRawY().

Answer (score 0):

[`Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#RELATIVE_TO_PARENT) specifies that the value you are providing is a float value to be multiplied by the width or height of the parent. `1.0` corresponds to `100%` of the parent's corresponding dimension.

An example of this would be animating a view completely off the screen by specifying `1.0` for `100%` creating an exit-right animation or `-1.0` for `-100%` creating an exit-left animation.

[TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float%29)